# None-root user commands not found

Tags: python, django, server, command, virtualenv

When I logged in as root , all commands will be executed . 
But when I logged in as another user, cant use any of these commands :

```
mkvirtualenv, activate , deactivate , workon , ....
```

The error is

> -bash: COMMAND : command not found

But accidentally i found `virtualenv` command will work instead of   `mkvirtualenv` But dont know why ?

anyone can help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurred because `virtualenvwrapper` not activated for none root users, append below lines on the your `.bashrc` file that located(or must be create if not exists) on the user home directory:

```
. $(which virtualenvwrapper.sh)
```

Logout and Login and try again...

Comment: daskhosh kako , daskhosh :)))

Comment: Azizi gompe golom :-*

Comment: agha man chanta soal az deploy kardane django daram . mituni hal koni vasam ?

Comment: Bia telegramam @moshen212

Comment: `. virtualenvwrapper.sh` works because bash searches the source file in the `$PATH` (exactly like `which`). And I recommend lazy loading: `source virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh`, it's much faster.